# React-native Getting error when running - cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

The app works perfectly with the emulator when I run react-native run android but when I try generating the apk it shows the following error[image]

Don't know what the problem is It works flawlessly in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know just like that what's the error... Did you follow all the steps ? : 
=> `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
=> `Place the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app`
=> `Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`with the informations you create(store and key password). 
`MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
 MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****`
=> `Edit the file android/app/build.gradle` to enable release version... like this : 
              => `...
                  android {
                  ...
                  defaultConfig { ... }
                  signingConfigs {
                  release {
                        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                          }
                  }
                  buildTypes {
                       release {
                                 ...
                                 signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                               }
                             }
                  }
                     ...`

=> And finishing , go on main repo and run this : `$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

=> `The generated APK can be found under android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`

All the precise informations can be found here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Comment: But I created a new project and without following the steps It worked ./gradlew assembleRelease gives the error

Answer (score 0):

So i finally found the answer I had to delete default.png file and rename the reference in js files don't know what caused the error. But deleting the file in res folder seemed to be a workaround, if anyone finds the cause do tell me but for now the problem is resolved